# Wait Observable in Angular Function

Tags: angular, observable

I have a service where I get data by sending a sql query;

```
  getList(model:sqlModel):Observable<apiResultModel<sqlResultModel>>{
    return this.http.post<apiResultModel<sqlResultModel>>(this.apiUrl,JSON.stringify(model),httpOptions);
  }
```

My service is running smoothly. but in a component I want to use this incoming data, I have to wait for the data to come.

```
 openInputPopup():void{
    const resModel = this.getSqlResult();--this should not go to the bottom line before it is completed 
    console.log('res',resModel);
    const modal = this.inputPopup.create({
      nzTitle: 'Component Settings',
      nzStyle:{'top':'20px', 'width':'60%'},
      nzContent: FormPopupModalComponent,
      nzViewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef,
      nzComponentParams: {   
        sqlResModel:resModel 
      },
      nzOnOk: () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))      
    });
    modal.afterClose.subscribe(a=>{
      var el = document.getElementById('popDeneme');
      this.popValue = modal.componentInstance.inputId;
    });
  }


  getSqlResult() :sqlResultModel{
    this.sqlModel.dbSourceId=1;
    this.sqlModel.limitperPage=1;
    this.sqlModel.pageNum=1;
    this.sqlModel.query="SELECT [CODE],[DEFINITION_] FROM [TEST].[dbo].[PRODUCTS]"
    var res = new sqlResultModel();
   
    this.sqlService.getList(this.sqlModel).subscribe(
      i=>{        
        res = i.Result;
        console.log('ok');
      }
    );

    return res;  --There should be no return before the getlist() function above is completed. Since getlist() is not complete, it returns the initial value and it doesn't work for me.  
  }
```

what do you suggest i do? I know it's a small point but I'm new to coding please help

Comment: There is no other way.. you are making a call to server so you have to wait, no other alternatives.

Comment: The question really is more about how the code can be executed after the observable resolves. You should look at RxJS operators switchMap and mergeMap

Answer (score 0):

you can use Rxjs Operators as mentioned before but you can also convert to promise and use await like this :

return this instead
`return this.sqlService.getList(this.sqlModel).toPromise()`

and use it like this :

```
async openInputPopup():void{
const resModel = await this.getSqlResult();
// your code 
}
```